# K&R C Exercise 1-9 *almost* solved

Tags: c, loops, io

K&R C Exercise 1-9 states:

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

I have nearly solved this exercise, but the code I've written (see below) always prints an extra space before the first nonspace character. So input that looks like this

> X(space)(space)X(space)(space)X(space)(space)X

results in output that looks like this

> (space)X(space)X(space)X(space)X

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;                     //current input character
    int s;                     //consecutive input space counter

    c = getchar();
    s = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' '){
            ++s;
            if (s == 1)        //uses the counter to print only the  
                putchar(' ');  //first space in each string of spaces
        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
            if (s != 0)            //resets the space counter when it  
                s = 0;             //encounters a non-space input character
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does my code always print a leading space when I run it?
How can I modify this code to print the first input character first instead of a leading space?

Comment: I'm curious why you are doing a getchar() before starting the while loop?  You end up discarding a character.

Comment: Well, you are missing a closing brace before the `return 0` to balance your while loop.  Aside form that, this code works as you decide the expected output to be.

Comment: Correct as the last two comments say, and it will work. Although `if (s != 0)` is unnecessary, just set `s = 0` anyway.

Comment: Perhaps testing `if (c == ' ') { if (s == 0) {s++; putchar (c); } } else ...` may provide an avenue. An alternate approach is just to capture the previous character, then it can be a simple `if (p != ' ') putchar(c); else if (c != ' ') putchar (c); p = c;`

Comment: I changed `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` to `while (c != EOF)`, and now I get an infinite stream of garbage output.  Something about the former was terminating the loop--how do I do that without losing a character?

Comment: If you are putting that in your loop test, `c` never changes and is never `EOF` (`-1`) (unless you change `c` in the loop body).

Comment: Also, I count 4 opening brackets and 4 closing brackets in my code example above, so I'm not sure how any of them are unbalanced.  I added an extra closing bracket before `return 0' anyway for diligences sake, and it was just errored as missing an opening bracket.

If three people see this unbalanced bracket and I don't, there must be something important that I don't understand.

Comment: You are missing the closing brace `}` immediately prior to `return 0;` to conclude the `while` loop `:)` If you keep your `if-else` statements indented consistently, it will become apparent. P.S. You are doing fine. C is an exact language, to master it, you just need to *slow down*... It takes time.

Comment: OK, after your edit, now throw away the first `c = getchar();`, change `if (s == 1)` to `if (s == 0)` and move `s++;` below it within braces along with `putchar(' ');`. Throw away the last `if (s != 0)`. See if that helps. (note: since you are not using the number of spaces, `s++;` can be simply `s = 1;`) If it all works, don't move on until you understand why it does, or doesn't.

Comment: @NathanielLindsey - were you able to arrive at a working solution? If so, you may post your solution as an answer. (while we don't encourage people to answer their own posts, in this case where the answers and comments given were to help you arrive at an answer rather than just giving you an answer, it is perfectly OK)

Answer (score 0):

Do not throw away the first `char`.  [@David Hoelzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160484/kr-c-exercise-1-9-almost-solved/35160996#comment58039368_35160484)

```
// Commented out
//c = getchar();

s = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
```

Also note unbalanced `}` near `return 0;`